# Browser version from IIS logs

Tags: internet-explorer, iis, browser

I am trying to determine if my users used IE 10 or IE 9 to access my Web Application. The user-agent column in IIS logs says the following:

> Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+7.0;+Windows+NT+6.1;+Trident/4.0;+SLCC2;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729;+.NET+CLR+3.0.30729;+Media+Center+PC+6.0;+.NET4.0C;+.NET4.0E;+InfoPath.1;+MS-RTC+LM+8)

I don't know what I can make of this. Does this mean they used IE 7.0? How would this log look if they used IE 9.0 or IE 10.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your visitor *probably* used MSIE 7, as seen by `compatible;+MSIE+7.0;`

If they were using IE 9, it would say `MSIE 9.0`, 10 would be `MSIE 10`

Note: This only applies up to MSIE 10, at 11 they changed to a new "Trident" format which you can see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/bg182625%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

You can see more [here](http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/msie-history.html)

Comment: "*Your visitor used MSIE 7*".... Well, it *probably* means that. Or they could have been using a later IE version in compatibility mode. Or they could have been using any browser that allows them to switch the UA string. Most likely they were indeed just using IE7, but you can't be absolutely certain.

Comment: Yes, very true. When dealing with User Agents, assume nothing is correct.

Comment: That actually looks like the IE 11 UA string. :)

Comment: I disagree with this answer.  This looks like the browser is using compatibility mode.  The "Trident" token in the User Agent string it's a more recent version of IE than IE7. However, I don't know how to determine the actual browser version from the User Agent string, so I can't provide an answer to this OP question.